# Ho to understand and fix syntax errors in p5.js?

Tags: javascript, java, processing, p5.js

I need to translate a Java code done in processing to p5.js to embed on html. I have started translating it, but it keeps throwing errors and can't fix them. I have very little experience with JavaScript and don't have the time to learn it.

It works perfectly on processing, but I used chat gpt to translate and it obviously didn't do a perfect job. I'm also suspicious because my inital code had 600 lines and this has only 300. How can I fix those syntax bugs and explain what I need to fix in terms of missing function or class declarations?

At function updateAA(x, y) it says "Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.ts(1068)". I'm not also sure if I need the "return this.rectOver" line at the end of the function. Do I? Also, at the last bracket that is supposed to close the class, it returns the error "Declaration or statement expected.ts(1128)".

```
let scenarioA;
let buttons;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  scenarioA = new ScenarioA();
  buttons = new Buttons();
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  scenarioA.display();
  buttons.display();
}

function mouseClicked() {
  buttons.mouseClicked();
}

class ScenarioA {
  scenarioAA() {
    // Scenario AA implementation
  }

  scenarioAB() {
    // Scenario AB implementation
  }

  scenarioAC() {
    // Scenario AC implementation
  }

  scenarioBA() {
    // Scenario BA implementation
  }

  scenarioBB() {
    // Scenario BB implementation
  }

  scenarioBC() {
    // Scenario BC implementation
  }

  scenarioCA() {
    // Scenario CA implementation
  }

  scenarioCB() {
    // Scenario CB implementation
  }

  scenarioCC() {
    // Scenario CC implementation
  }

  display() {
    // Display implementation
  }
}

class Buttons {
  constructor() {
    this.rectOver = false;
    this.x1 = 189;
    this.x2 = 244;
    this.x3 = 299;
    this.y1 = 189;
    this.y2 = 224;
    this.y3 = 259;
    this.textspacingx = 14;
    this.textspacingy = 22;
    this.buttonlength = 50;
    this.buttonwidth = 50; // Added missing property declaration
  }

  table() {
    strokeWeight(0.5);
    fill(255);
    stroke(0);
    rect(120, 130, 230, 160);
  }

   range() {
    text("Low", 145, 210);
    text("Mid", 145, 245);
    text("High", 145, 280);
    push();
    let angle2 = radians(270);
    translate(140, 260);
    rotate(angle2);
    let nuclear;
    nuclear = createFont("Avenir-Light", 20);
    textFont(nuclear, 20);
    fill(0);
    textAlign(CORNER);
    text("Climate", 0, 0);
    pop();
    text("Low", 195, 185);
    text("Mid", 250, 185);
    text("High", 305, 185);
    text("Nuclear", 230, 155);
  }

   display() {
    this.updateAA(mouseX, mouseY);
    if (this.rectOver) {
      fill(220);
    } else {
      fill(240);
    }
    stroke(200);
    rect(this.x1, this.y1, this.buttonlength, this.buttonwidth, 2);
    fill(0);

    this.updateAB(mouseX, mouseY);
    if (this.rectOver) {
      fill(220);
    } else {
      fill(240);
    }
    stroke(200);
    rect(this.x2, this.y1, this.buttonlength, this.buttonwidth, 2);
    fill(0);

    this.updateAC(mouseX, mouseY);
    if (this.rectOver) {
      fill(220);
    } else {
      fill(240);
    }
    stroke(200);
    rect(this.x3, this.y1, this.buttonlength, this.buttonwidth, 2);
    fill(0);

    this.updateBA(mouseX, mouseY);
    if (this.rectOver) {
      fill(220);
    } else {
      fill(240);
    }
    stroke(200);
    rect(this.x1, this.y2, this.buttonlength, this.buttonwidth, 2);
    fill(0);

    this.updateBB(mouseX, mouseY);
    if (this.rectOver) {
      fill(220);
    } else {
      fill(240);
    }
    stroke(200);
    rect(this.x2, this.y2, this.buttonlength, this.buttonwidth, 2);
    fill(0);

    this.updateBC(mouseX, mouseY);
    if (this.rectOver) {
      fill(220);
    } else {
      fill(240);
    }
    stroke(200);
    rect(this.x3, this.y2, this.buttonlength, this.buttonwidth, 2);
    fill(0);

    this.updateCA (mouseX, mouseY);
    if (this.rectOver) {
      fill(220);
    } else {
      fill(240);
    }
    stroke(200);
    rect(this.x1, this.y3, this.buttonlength, this.buttonwidth, 2);
    fill(0);

    this.updateCB(mouseX, mouseY);
    if (this.rectOver) {
      fill(220);
    } else {
      fill(240);
    }
    stroke(200);
    rect(this.x2, this.y3, this.buttonlength, this.buttonwidth, 2);
    fill(0);

    this.updateCC(mouseX, mouseY);
    if (this.rectOver) {
      fill(220);
    } else {
      fill(240);
    }
    stroke(200);
    rect(this.x3, this.y3, this.buttonlength, this.buttonwidth, 2);
    fill(0);
  }
/////////STOPPED FIXING HERE

   function updateAA(x, y){
    if (this.overRectAA(this.x1, this.y1, this.buttonlength, this.buttonwidth)) {
      this.rectOver = true;
    } else {
      this.rectOver = false;
    }
    return this.rectOver;
  }

  function updateAB(x, y) {
    if (this.overRectAB(this.x2, this.y1, this.buttonlength, this.buttonwidth)) {
      this.rectOver = true;
    } else {
      this.rectOver = false;
    }
  }

  function updateAC(x, y) {
    if (this.overRectAC(this.x3, this.y1, this.buttonlength, this.buttonwidth)) {
      this.rectOver = true;
    } else {
      this.rectOver = false;
    }
  }

  function updateBA(x, y) {
    if (this.overRectBA(this.x1, this.y2, this.buttonlength, this.buttonwidth)) {
      this.rectOver = true;
    } else {
      this.rectOver = false;
    }
  }
  function updateBB(x, y) {
    if (this.overRectBB(this.x2, this.y2, this.buttonlength, this.buttonwidth)) {
      this.rectOver = true;
    } else {
      this.rectOver = false;
    }
  }
  function updateBC(x, y) {
    if (this.overRectBC(this.x2, this.y3, this.buttonlength, this.buttonwidth)) {
      this.rectOver = true;
    } else {
      this.rectOver = false;
    }
  }
  function updateCA(x, y) {
    if (this.overRectCA(this.x3, this.y1, this.buttonlength, this.buttonwidth)) {
      this.rectOver = true;
    } else {
      this.rectOver = false;
    }
  }

  function overRectAA(x, y, width, height) {
    if (mouseX >= x && mouseX <= x + width && mouseY >= y && mouseY <= y + height) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  function overRectAB(x, y, width, height) {
    if (mouseX >= x && mouseX <= x + width && mouseY >= y && mouseY <= y + height) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  function overRectAC(x, y, width, height) {
    if (mouseX >= x && mouseX <= x + width && mouseY >= y && mouseY <= y + height) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }



  function  mouseClicked() {
    if (this.overRectAA(this.x1, this.y1, this.buttonlength, this.buttonwidth)) {
      scenarioA.scenarioAA();
    }

    if (this.overRectAB(this.x2, this.y1, this.buttonlength, this.buttonwidth)) {
      scenarioA.scenarioAB();
    }

    if (this.overRectAC(this.x3, this.y1, this.buttonlength, this.buttonwidth)) {
      scenarioA.scenarioAC();
    }
  }
}
```

The code is supposed to output an interactive graph with 9 scenarios that alternate based on the hovering of the mouse. I uploaded an image of one of those scenarios here. It works perfectly on processing, but with this code, it won't go due to syntax issues. When I used a previous version provided by chatgpt it worked, but was missing almost everything, which leads me to believe it cut out a lot of the code. What is missing?

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: At function updateAA(x, y) it says "Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.ts(1068)". I'm not also sure if I need the "return this.rectOver" line at the end of the function. Do I? Also, at the last bracket that is supposed to close the class, it returns the error "Declaration or statement expected.ts(1128)".

Comment: Please include all relevant information in your post and not in the comments.

Comment: i just put it there

Comment: I'm struggling to understand your code.  Why don't ```table()```, ```display()```, et.al start with the ```function``` reserved word?

Comment: That's the issue, I don't know. This is what I got back when translated from Java

Comment: What do you mean "This is what I got back when translated from Java"? Who made the translation?

Answer (score 0):

Using the `function` keyword where it doesn't belong, on methods inside of the `Buttons` class seems to be your main issue.

JavaScript uses different syntax to declare global or local functions than to declare class members. Java doesn't have such a distinction because there are no global functions, all functions are declared on a class.

When declaring a global function (like the `setup` and `draw` at the top of your file), you use the following syntax:

```js
function your_function_name(arg1, arg2) {
}
```

When declaring a method on a class the syntax is very similar but without the `function` keyword:

```js
class YourClass {
  your_method_name(arg1, arg2) {
  }
}
```